# Problems when reading mysql data filtered by list using python

Tags: python, mysql, filter

I am trying to filter my datatable in mysql for further processing based on a set of values from another datatable. However, after executing the code shown below, I seem to be getting Programming Error. Not sure why this is wrong. Hope to seek any advice.

Error obtained:

> ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1064
> (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

```
staging = "SELECT * FROM staging_table WHERE status = 'New'"
df_staging = pd.read_sql_query(staging, connection)
lst = df_staging['SN'].tolist()

final = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE SN IN {lst}"
df_final = pd.read_sql_query(final, connection)
```